# Why do CTRL+Z doesn't works after issuing bg command?

Tags: ubuntu, process

I  suspend a NodeJS instance by issuing CTRL+Z then bring it back by issuing bg command but after that I can't issue CTRL+Z as it has no effect.

What causes this?

Comment: https://superuser.com/q/1635571/432690

Comment: Logical issue is that you can have a hundred background jobs (but only one foreground process). What should Ctrl-Z do then?

Comment: @Paul_Pedant I'm debugging a stream, I need to pause and resume the process.

Comment: What is the reason you used `bg`, not `fg`?

Comment: You can stop and start the foreground process as often as you want. Putting it in the background is the issue. Suspend with Ctrl-Z. Continue with the job number that shell shows you when it suspends -- e.g. just type `%1` (on Bash). Use separate windows for diagnostics. If you need more help on "debugging a stream", expand your question (maybe look at `man pv` and/or `man tee` and `tail -f`).

Comment: `fg` will restart the most recently suspended process. If you have more than one suspended process, you may specify a job number like `fg %3`. `%3` is a shorter version of that. `bg` will do the same, but run the job as background. The `jobs -l`command will list all jobs owned by the current shell: job number, status, process id, and command. If you have a foreground job, Bash will not be reading the input, so you have to Ctrl-Z it just to be able to use job control.